# How to execute insert into in django with raw sql commands from a html form

Tags: django

I'm using Django and I have a form in html which gets the data to store in the database, I would like to know how can I insert this data without using ORM, just pure SQL commands. Do I have to create a model?
Does anyone have any example?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 0):

Actually Django's SQL management is very good. I don't understand why you choose use Raw SQL. However, if you still need, django allows using raw sql query.

There is two options:

1. Create your model and manipulate with sql queries like here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/
2. Use stored procedures in your db and call them from django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#calling-stored-procedures

OR

Understand [Making Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/) in Django and using [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/)